# Flex 4 Change Main Application Background Color at Runtime

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, styles

Is it possible within Flex 4 to change the background color of an `<s:Application>` at runtime? I've seen examples of how to do this with the MX version of the Application component, but not the spark version.

I cannot bind the `backgroundColor` property to a variable and modify that. However, I am thinking that I should use the `styleManager` property of the component to perform this change.

Could anyone explain how to do this?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you go through this:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fee.html

The video tutorial steps through using CSS and using skins in Flex 4 which are the primary means of changing visual components.

Application has a backgroundColor style still:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Application.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
               creationComplete="application1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">
    <s:layout>
        <s:HorizontalLayout/>
    </s:layout>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                setStyle('backgroundColor',0xCCCCCC);
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:Button click="setStyle('backgroundColor','0xff0000');" label="turn red"/>
    <s:Button click="setStyle('backgroundColor','0x0000ff');" label="turn blue"/>
    <s:Button click="setStyle('backgroundColor','0x00ff00');" label="turn green"/>
</s:Application>
```

A Better way to go IMO

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <s:layout>
        <s:HorizontalLayout/>
    </s:layout>
    <fx:Style>
        @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
        @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";
        s|Application{
            backgroundColor:#CCCCCC;
        }
    </fx:Style>
    <s:Button click="setStyle('backgroundColor','0xff0000');" label="turn red"/>
    <s:Button click="setStyle('backgroundColor','0x0000ff');" label="turn blue"/>
    <s:Button click="setStyle('backgroundColor','0x00ff00');" label="turn green"/>
</s:Application>
```

Better still pull the CSS out into it's own file and just reference it with a

```
<fx:Style source="myStyle.css"/>
```

Comment: Thank you. That is what I am trying, but it does not change the background color. I am using this within a `creationComplete` event handler.

Comment: @spryno724 I tried that and it worked as well, using Flex 4.6.0

Comment: there ya go :) yah skinning is great but can sometimes be a bit tricky

Comment: Thank you for the excellent examples! I'm going to stick with the AS method, since I have my background stored in an application Config class for easy modification, something that you can't really do with CSS.

Comment: Cool beans, was just a suggestion definitely not a necessity.  Just found that it works out much better on big projects when styles and scripts and layout are all separated to some degree, but it totally depends on the project.

Comment: Thank for simply suggesting ideas, but not pushing them on me. I can't tell you how many times I've seen developers, even on SO, try to push their ideas on other people, regardless of whether or not they know the specific circumstances, just because "it's the standard way", "best practice", or even "not stupid". Its actually a breath of fresh air to have a simple suggestion, rather than pushy advice. Thanks again ;)

Answer (score 1):

You may try it with

```
FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.setStyle("backgroundColor", 0xff0000);  // that would turn it into bright red
FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.setStyle("backgroundAlpha", 1);  // Sometimes background color is ignored when background alpha is zero
```

If the background color does not change, that means one of your component might be dictating the background color.